# What is the suitable IP address for DNS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

i am configure a new Windows Server in a new network however i do not know what should i put for my DNS server address. Here is my network configuration:

IP: 10.0.0.7
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 10.0.0.5

Please guide me on this. Thank you and appreciate for the help

Comment: You should use the IP address of the DNS server. Kind of obvious if you stop to think about it.

Answer (score 3):

Given it's an internal address then you'll either need to use an existing internal DNS server or if your gateway is setup to just NAT everything (which I doubt it is) then you could try someone like Google's DNS servers at 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you have configured the server to be. If its an Active Directory Server with integrated DNS Zone, Microsoft recommends you add the loopback address (127.0.0.1) as the primary DNS then another DNS Server in the Domain as the secondary. You could then set a forwarder in your internal DNS server to an external DNS Server for internet name resolution.

If you just want the server to be able to browse the internet then all you need is to follow Choppers advice

Answer (score 1):

Best option: ask you network administrator, i.e. the one that gave you the IP 10.0.0.7.

Other option: ask your ISP for the DNS servers they suggest.

Where possible, I personally use 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220

Answer (score 0):

**DNS**

You can use any DNS you want. For example I always use 194.179.1.100. But the best option is to use:

- The DNS recommended by your ISP (probably the DNS that other machines in your network are using now)
- If not sure use the one that you have in your machine configured (the one you are using to read this)

**IP Address**

You are using a Private class A that allows you to use 16Million of IPs (exactly 16.777.216). Maybe you should use a class C. Usually people use class C for small networks.

Here you have an example of the different types of Private Class Addresses:

- Private Class C: IP: 192.168.0.7
  subnet mask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway:
  192.168.0.5
- Private Class B: IP: 172.16.0.7
  subnet mask: 255.255.0.0 Gateway:
  172.16.0.5
- Private Class A: IP: 10.0.0.7 subnet
  mask: 255.0.0.0 Gateway: 10.0.0.5

You have more info here :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address (Check IPv4 private addresses section)

EDIT NOTES:

- I am assuming that you want your host to be x.x.x.7 and your gateway will be x.x.x.5
- Be careful that all the machines in your network must have same subnet mask.

Comment: You may want to finish reading the entire article to which you've linked... [Classes are obsolete terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network#The_replacement_of_classes), please read up on [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) as this supplanted classes many years ago..

Comment: @jscott. Thanks! I know. But I thought explaining this in depth will cause more trouble than benefit to @asley

Comment: Explaining something incorrectly is not beneficial to anyone. Please have a [search for "classless"](http://serverfault.com/search?q=classless) to get a feel for how strongly this community feels about the subject.